# Way to call new modules after exe is compiled with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --onefile script.py
```

script.py

```
while True:
   x=raw_input('enter code: ')
   exec(x.strip())
```

copy new module into root of script.exe
'newmodule'
run script.exe

```
enter code: import newmodule
```

-------this errors, module not found

a way to do this?

Comment: pyinstaller freezes your code and makes it's own python interpreter that executes whatever was in that code.  those `exec` calls should be to it's own isolated interpreter.  so, unless your `newmodule` was part of the original executable package, it won't be reachable.

Comment: Checkout [multipackage-bundles](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#multipackage-bundles)